# DOM element retrieval yields inconsistent data

Tags: javascript

I have a div element which is populated with new innerHTML every time a forward or back button is clicked.  But, when I use JS to store its information in a variable and `console.log` it I get unexpected data.

```
var unitName = document.querySelector("#unitName");
console.log(unitName, unitName.innerHTML.length);
```

The `unitName` will display as the current `unitName`, but the `unitName.innerHTML.length` will display the value of the previous `unitName`'s HTML length.

Using setTimeOut will work around this and match up the apporopriate values, but is there another way to do this that doesn't involve using setTimeOut?

Comment: Could you give us some sample HTML code that you have tried this on?

Comment: function call should do, can you share the whole code.

Comment: Can't share full code, but the html element would be something simple like <div id="untiName">Unit info here</div>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: `length` will be the length when you executed the `console.log()`. Objects in the console are "live", so if you expand the object after the element is modified it will show the updated value.

Comment: The id in the div doesn't match that in the Javascript, Other than that it works fine